# Login cookies on mobile

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

so recently i have decided to write a special website and i got it finished, but now i came across a problem.

```
<a href='#' id='logout'><li>odjava</li></a>
```

With this link, i call ajax function logout (check below) which sends a php request to clear cookies.

```
function logout(){
    //alert("blabla"); this one pops up.
$.ajax({
    url: "./backend/local.php",
    data: {
        f: "logout"
        }
    }).done(function(data){
                    //alert("bubu"); this one doesn't on mobile.
        location.reload();
    });
}
```

This is the php function:

```
function logout(){
    unset($_COOKIE['user']);
    unset($_COOKIE['id']);
    unset($_COOKIE['profile']);
    setcookie("user", "", time() - 3600, "/");
    setcookie("id", "", time() - 3600, "/");
    setcookie("profile", "", time() - 3600, "/");
}
```

Now the problem is, that this works normally on desktop, but on mobile phones, it will not logout.

Any idea what i did wrong? This started out of nowhere. Worked fine before.

Thank you and have a nice day

Comment: Add `.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
  alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
});` to see if there's an error and what it is...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i found the problem. Thank you. The problem was, that i was using the link

odjava

Looks like the a tag caused the problems. I removed the a tag, and added id to the li element. Works perfectly. Thank you Tony and everyone else.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that something in your PHP script could be failing? If something went wrong the `done` will never be triggered. You could switch the event to `always` and it will trigger even if the script failed.

It is probably a good idea to check to see what is failing though. You can check this with the `fail` event.

```
$.ajax({

    url: "./backend/local.php",
    data: {
        f: "logout"
    }

}).always(function(){

    location.reload();

}).fail(.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) { 

    alert( "Error: " + textStatus ); 

});
```

Comment: `always` callback will be excuted before the `fail` callback... So I'm not sure the alert will be seen...

Comment: okay, thank you for the response.

I tried it, and all i get is for textStatus to be "error", errorThrown is empty.

This only happens on mobile :/

Comment: @Programmer What does the code look like when you are setting one of the cookies outside the logout function?

Comment: gist: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/69a957e5531aada682ab1f8695529b72

Comment: Any idea? I can't come up with anything :/

Comment: @Programmer my only thought would have been that maybe there is some conflict between the root directory you are saving your cookies in for your desktop browser, and the root directory you are saving from your mobile browser. I have a feeling something like that is causing a problem.

Comment: Okay, so i have been playing with it a little.
It works every 5-10th try.
But ajax still fails (as fail function is called).
I never had any problems with this...

this is weird.

Comment: @Programmer maybe the script is timing out if it takes a long time to execute. Try setting the property `timeout: 10000`

Comment: Okay i tried this as well. Doesn't help :/

still the same result.

Comment: @Programmer does the script fail if you call it directly outside of the ajax call?

Comment: @Programmer maybe try structuring your ajax call like the way I added in the edit.

Comment: Okay i found the problem.
Thank you.

The problem was, that i was using the link 
`<a href='.' id='logout'><li>odjava</li></a>`

Looks like the a tag caused the problems. I removed the a tag, and added id to the li element. Works perfectly.

Thanks again.